# Is there any permission present in android to read a file from the internet

Tags: android

i am asking this , because i have tried .... some codes and created my own for accessing a file , which is present in internet , i want to read that file but my code is not working so i am asking this question because in SD_CARD case we have to provide the permission to our android app , that you can access it .... by this reason every time my application is terminated & my code is :-

```
    try 
{
        url = new URL ("http://sites.google.com/site/androidersite/text.txt");
} 
    catch (MalformedURLException e) 
    {
    Toast.makeText( this , "url String mein hi error aa raha hai .. oo" ,          Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
}

    HttpURLConnection  urlConnection = null ;
    try 
    {
    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
} 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        Toast.makeText( this , "HTTP url connection mein error" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
}

    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) 
    {
         Toast.makeText( this , "connect hua" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    } 
    else 
    {
         Toast.makeText( this , "nahi hua connect" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    }

    try 
    {
         BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

         String StringBuffer;
         String stringText = "";

         while ((StringBuffer = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) 
         {
              stringText += StringBuffer;
         }

         bufferReader.close();

    } 
    catch (MalformedURLException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

& for permissions i have provided , it .

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: Can you post your logcat for which exact error you are getting?

Comment: I guess it is the another case of `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.your above code is in `Thread`?

Comment: @Naeem , no ! inside  onCreate()

Comment: @tushar see my answer and you shouldn't perform any network operation in ``onCreate()`` or any methods within the main thread and you might get ANR Dialog

Comment: you have to use AsyncTask, refer this http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html